# Convert an array to string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Still new in PHP and I am trying to convert an array to string in my code below:

```
$totalProfitsArray = print_r($profits['totalProfit']);
```

If I echo the `$totalProfitsArray` variable above i get this result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [count] => 44.35 ) )
```

which is fine but i want to echo only the 44.35 value. So i tried to use the implode method like this:

```
implode("", $totalProfitsArray);
```

but still didn't work and i get this error:

> implode(): Invalid arguments passed

What I am doing wrong? Is there any other easy way to convert the array in string and print the result?

Comment: If you `var_export` your original `$profits` array, it makes it easier for others to understand your data structure and consume/work with the data.

Comment: The return of `print_r` will likely be `true`,  so your assignment above to an array is misguided.

Comment: If you want an array as a string to be used reused later by PHP then consider using the built-in `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions.    ....    https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: On `print_r()` always returns true unless the 2nd parameter is specified as `true`, in which `print_r()` will return a string of it's results as opposed to echoing the contents.     ....     https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting value in another array like this

```
$arr = array(array('count' => 44.35));
```

to get the inner value you have to access it like this:

```
print_r($profits['totalProfit'][0]['count']);
$totalProfitsArray = $profits['totalProfit'][0]['count'];
```

Comment: Thanks mate, now it gives the right result. I will check your answer as accepted

Comment: You probably don't want to assign to a print_r (with the exception of the second argument).  Here the print_r is unnecessary.  Targeting the count index of the zeroth element of the array should be enough.

Comment: yup my bad, i am editing it

Comment: No worries! i already removed the print_r and works just fine.